# How do I set up a loading state with my next auth signin?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When I submit the form, it calls the signin function and everything happens behind the scene and I'm unable to set a state for it.

I'm importing this to make the signin work

```
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
```

This is the submit function that fires when I submit the form:

```
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const res = await signIn("credentials", {
        username: input.username,
        password: input.password,
        redirect: false,
    });
};
```

extra detail, this is what my [...nextauth].js api looks like

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import dbConnect from "../../../util/mongodb";
import user from "../../../models/user";
import bcryptjs from "bcryptjs";

export default NextAuth({
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },

    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "credentials",
            credentials: {},
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                await dbConnect();

                const { username, password } = credentials;
                const users = await user.findOne({ username: username });

                const decodedPassword = await bcryptjs.compare(password, users.password);

                if (!users) {
                    throw new Error("No such user in the database");
                }

                if (users.username === username && !decodedPassword) {
                    throw new Error("Password does not match");
                }

                if (users.username === username && decodedPassword) {
                    const { password, ...others } = users;
                    return {
                        id: users._id,
                        username: users.username,
                        firstname: users.firstname,
                    };
                }
            },
        }),
    ],
    pages: {
        signIn: "/auth/signin",
    },
    callbacks: {
        async session({ token, session }) {
            session.user = token.user;
            return session;
        },

        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                token.user = user;
            }
            return token;
        },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [loading, setLoading]= useState(false)

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
          setLoading(true);
          const res = await signIn("credentials", {
            username: input.username,
            password: input.password,
            redirect: false
          });
          setLoading(false);
        } catch (error) {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      };
```